# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Float'

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

I know this question has been asked before but none of the questions were helpful hence asking again..

I am using graphene and parsing some Elasticsearch data before passing it to Graphene

PFB :- my resolved function

```
def resolve_freelancers(self, info):
    session = get_session()
    [ids, scores] = self._get_freelancers()
    freelancers = session.query(FreelancerModel).filter(FreelancerModel.id.in_(ids)).all()

    for index in range(len(ids)):
        print("index", scores[index])
        freelancers[index].score = scores[index]

    if self.sort:
        reverse = self.sort.startswith("-")
        self.sort = self.sort.replace("-", "")
        if self.sort == "alphabetical":
            freelancers = sorted(freelancers, key=lambda f: f.name if f.name else "", reverse=reverse)
        if self.sort == "created":
            freelancers = sorted(freelancers, key=lambda f: f.created_on, reverse=reverse)
        if self.sort == "modified":
            freelancers = sorted(freelancers, key=lambda f: f.modified_at, reverse=reverse)
    freelancers = [Freelancer(f) for f in freelancers[self.start:self.end]]
    session.close()
    return freelancers
```

now if I do

```
print(freelancers[index].score)
```

it gives me `10.989184` and the type of this is `<class 'float'>`

In my `class Freelancer(graphene.ObjectType):`

I have added `score = graphene.Float()`

Now when I try to add `score` to my query it gives the error .. otherwise there is no issue .. all I am interested is in getting that score value in the json response .. I do not understand what is causing this error and I am fairly new to Python so any advise will be appreciated.

Please feel free to ask for additional code or information as I have tried to paste whatever I thought was relevant

Answer (score 0):

So I can't comment or I would, and I very well may be wrong, but here goes.

My guess is that somewhere you are calling `float(score)`, but the `graphene.Float()` type cannot be directly converted to a Python float via `float()`. This is probably due to the `graphene.Float` type having so much data it can hold in its data structure due to inheriting from `graphene.Scalar` ([graphene GH/Scalars](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/types/scalars.py)).

My guess would be to hunt down the `float()` call and remove it. If that doesn't work, I would then move onto `Float.num` field in your query.

Again, all conjecture here, but I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I cannot pass the fields directly to the Graphene Object and we need to pass it within the **init** method of the class which has the Graphene Object and then we need to return in a resolver method ( in my case resolve_score )